# Vuetify datatable rows per page dropdown is not showing properly

Tags: vuetify.js

I included two screenshots here, one before I open dropdown and one after.  [image: one before I open rows per page] [image: and one after]

Whenever I open it, it just opens more padding in the page and rows per page dropdown opens in another place.

This error happens with any of [Vuetify examples provided in docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) even the most basic ones.

Also I wrapped in v-app but still it shows that wrong behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure you have

```
<v-app id="my_vue_app">
// vue stuff here
</v-app>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to wrap the entire project in 'v-app' after it didn't work because I wrapped only one component.

Comment: glad that i was able to help! I struggled with this myself at one point ;)